# How to create tabbed menus with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I came across a Wordpress page at http://www.houseofbeef.net/menu that has a tabbed menu. I'm not a Wordpress guy and I wondered how hard this was to do in WordPress. I have the "WordPress - the missing manual" book and didn't see anything like it there.

Is there a widget or plugin that sets this up to make it easy?

I'm not asking for the code to do this, just is it simple? (Possible answers: "Yes, you can use Widget A or Plugin B" or, "No, it's not simple. You have to use custom HTML.")

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Tabbed navigation is in no direct relation to WordPress. If you want a WordPress answer, you will receive instructions on how to install a plugin that does it, or then an answer that tells you how to enqueue tabnav scripts and styles inside the theme code. Ask with HTML/CSS/JS in mind and then learn to implement that into a WordPress theme.

Comment: Do you know of a WordPress plugin that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely using jQuery UI [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

I highly doubt they linked WP menus to the tabs - it's more likely they went the straight HTML route.  All you need to do is include the javascript and set up the html as the demo shows on the included page.

Comment: I don't think they used jQuery UI Tabs.  At least I don't see jQuery UI loaded anywhere for the page, which is what made me think it might be already baked into WP. But from the comments here, and  the fact that my "WP Missing Manual" book has nothing on it,  I suspect now that it's not in WP and  they got a real coder to do it with raw HTML/JavaScript. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I hadn't inspected the code at all, but they must use something similar.  There is no built in wordpress tabs.  There are probably many plugins out there that can provide that functionality.  good luck! @Steve